# Iterating an array of items in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have an index.js from which I am calling util.js as below :

**util.js**

```
module.exports.getResult = json => {
  return json.hits.hits.map(element => {
    const { _source } = element;

    return _source.details
      .filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('deliveryDetails'))
      .map(item => {
        return item.deliveryDetails
          .filter(deliveryDetail => deliveryDetail.noOfItems > 0)
          .map(deliveryDetail => {
            return {
              id: item.Id,
              name: _source.name,
              noOfItems: deliveryDetail.noOfItems,
            };
          });
      });
  });
};
```

Since I am returning multiple times the result from innermost .map is changed into an array of array. Is this what is expected when iterating or I am doing it wrong?

Then to get the result in one final array I have to do below in index.js:

```
const temp = helper.getResult(json);
const result = [].concat.apply([], [].concat.apply([], temp));
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - use `flat`. To get the depth, you just work out the `length + 2`.

```
const result = temp.flat(temp.length + 2);
```

Use a recursive function for `reduce`.

```
const flattenDeep = arr => arr.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(Array.isArray(c) ? flattenDeep(c) : c), []);
const result = flattenDeep(temp);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.flat` is not(yet) supported in the Node.js 10 release line, so that is something to keep in mind

Comment: Yeah - there are a heap of polyfills though- just use reduce.

Comment: @JackBashford I am very new to node js. Could you give me a sample example for my case to use reduce.

Comment: Sure @iAmLearning - just give me a sec.

Comment: Edited @iAmLearning, does that suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.flattenDeep = function() {
   return this.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(val.flattenDeep()) : acc.concat(val), []);
}


const result =  temp.flattenDeep();
```

Comment: please do NOT modify the prototype chain.